# C++ - checking a string for all values in an array

Tags: c++, find

I have some parsed text from the Vision API, and I'm filtering it using keywords, like so:

```
    if (finalTextRaw.find("File") != finalTextRaw.npos)
{
    LogMsg("Found Menubar");
}
```

E.g., if the keyword "File" is found anywhere within the string `finalTextRaw`, then the function is interrupted and a log message is printed.

This method is very reliable. But I've inefficiently just made a bunch of if-else-if statements in this fashion, and as I'm finding more words that need filtering, I'd rather be a little more efficient. Instead, I'm now getting a string from a config file, and then parsing that string into an array:

```
    string filterWords = GetApp()->GetFilter();
    std::replace(filterWords.begin(), filterWords.end(), ',', ' ');  ///replace ',' with ' '
    vector<int> array;
    stringstream ss(filterWords);
    int temp;
    while (ss >> temp)
        array.push_back(temp); ///create an array of filtered words
```

And I'd like to have just one `if` statement for checking that string against the array, instead of many of them for checking the string against each keyword I'm having to manually specify in the code. Something like this:

```
        if (finalTextRaw.find(array) != finalTextRaw.npos)
{
    LogMsg("Found filtered word");
}
```

Of course, that syntax doesn't work, and it's surely more complicated than that, but hopefully you get the idea: if any words from my array appear anywhere in that string, that string should be ignored and a log message printed instead.

Any ideas how I might fashion such a function? I'm guessing it's going to necessitate some kind of loop.

Comment: Do you know the number of words in the filter? And in the raw text?

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from Thomas's answer, a ranged for loop offers a neat solution:

```
for (const auto &word : words)
{
   if (finalTextRaw.find(word) != std::string::npos)
   {
        // word is found.
        // do stuff here or call a function.
        break;  // stop the loop.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Thomas, the most efficient way is to split both texts into a list of words. Then use `std::set_intersection` to find occurrences in both lists. You can use `std::vector` as long it is sorted. You end up with `O(n*log(n))` (with n = max words), rather than `O(n*m)`.

Split sentences to words:

```
auto split(std::string_view sentence) {
    auto result = std::vector<std::string>{};
    auto stream = std::istringstream{sentence.data()};    

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), std::back_inserter(result));

    return result;
}
```

Find words existing in both lists. This only works for sorted lists (like sets or manually sorted vectors).

```
auto intersect(std::vector<std::string> a, std::vector<std::string> b) {
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());

    auto result = std::vector<std::string>{};
    std::set_intersection(std::move_iterator{a.begin()},
                          std::move_iterator{a.end()}, 
                          b.cbegin(), b.cend(),
                          std::back_inserter(result));

    return result;
}
```

Example of how to use.

```
int main() {
    const auto result = intersect(split("hello my name is mister raw"),
                                  split("this is the final raw text"));

    for (const auto& word: result) {
      // do something with word
    }
}
```

Note that this makes sense when working with large or undefined number of words. If you know the limits, you might want to use *easier* solutions (provided by other answers).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fundamental, brute force, loop:

```
unsigned int quantity_words = array.size();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity_words; ++i)
{
   std::string word = array[i];
   if (finalTextRaw.find(word) != std::string::npos)
   {
        // word is found.
        // do stuff here or call a function.
        break;  // stop the loop.
   }
}
```

The above loop takes each word in the array and searches the `finalTextRaw` for the word.

There are better methods using some `std` algorithms.  I'll leave that for other answers.

**Edit 1: maps and association**
The above code is bothering me because there are too many passes through the `finalTextRaw` string.

Here's another idea:

1. Create a `std::set` using the words in `finalTextRaw`.
2. For each word in your `array`, check for existence in the set.
   This reduces the quantity of searches (it's like searching a tree).

You should also investigate creating a set of the words in `array` and finding the intersection between the two sets.

Comment: Ah, it seems I'm getting `Error C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from '_Ty' to 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'`. I _think_ in this context that means my `array` isn't actually being defined? I guess I can't be sure my first block of code is generating the array properly in the first place.

Comment: @Chopin we would need to see your actual code to answer that.